# Django REST framework foreign keys and filtering

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have following models in django app:

**models.py**:

```
class Make(BaseModel):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32) #alfa-romeo
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32) #Alfa Romeo

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Model(BaseModel):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make)  #Alfa Romeo
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64) # line[2]
    engine_capacity = models.IntegerField()
    trim = models.CharField(max_length=128) # line[4]
```

And **serializers.py**:

```
from .models import Make,Model
from rest_framework import serializers


class MakeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Make
        fields = ('url', 'slug', 'name')


class ModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('url', 'make', 'name', 'trim', 'engine_capacity')
```

and also **views.py**:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Make, Model
from .serializers import MakeSerializer, ModelSerializer


class MakeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Make.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MakeSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    make = MakeSerializer
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

What I need to to, I want to fetch all Models manufactured by specific make.
How can I get all models with particular make foreign key using query params? And my 2nd question - can I filter results using queryparams to get models with specific engine_capacity?

One comment: It would be perfect, if I can to query results using something like this in url: `/api/models/?make=ford` where *make* is `slug` field in `Make` model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

urls.py

```
url('^model/by/(?P<make>\w+)/$', ModelByMakerList.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
class ModelByMakerList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all models by
        the maker passed in the URL
        """
        maker = self.kwargs['make']
        return Model.objects.filter(make=maker)
```

For more info [checkout the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering).

You can also use filtering with QUERY_PARAMS, but IMHO this looks better.

Answer (score 44):

You can specify `filter_fields = ('make__slug', )` in your view set. Don't forget to include `filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )` as well. Also you will need to add `django-filter` dependency.

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('make__slug',)
```

Then you query like `/api/models/?make__slug=ford`. Note double underscore symbol.

[Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).

If you don't like `make__slug` keyword argument in the URL, then you can create a filter class:

```
import django_filters

from myapp.models import Make


class ModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    make = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name="make__slug",
                                            queryset=Make.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('make',)
```

and then

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    make = MakeSerializer
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ModelFilter
```

`/api/models/?make=ford` should work.

Comment: I tried to use your solution which looked straight forward and clean,but the `name` argument kept giving me errors.

Comment: If you are referring to name attribute in `django_filters.ModelsChoiceFilter(name="make_slug")` then it should be "field_name". It was renamed in recent releases of `django_filters` since my original answer was posted. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @vladimir-prudnikov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658965/241240):

Things changed a bit in recent versions of django-filter. You probably want:

```py
class ModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    make = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='make__slug',
                                            to_field_name='slug',
                                            queryset=Make.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('make',)
```

See https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#field-name and https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#to-field-name

Comment: use `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` instead of `ModelChoiceFilter`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in your view is something like this:
It is called "Lookups that span relationships"

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(make__name__exact='Alfa Romeo')
```

the filtering of models with specific engine capacity is similar

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(engine_capacity__exact=5)
```

if you want both filters combined, you can chain them:

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(make__name__exact='Alfa Romeo').filter(engine_capacity__exact=5)
```

more examples can be found here [django query making](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: I know how to query standard Django models, I need to do the same with Django Rest Framework